# Como modifico un link

Tags: html, botón, enlace

Quiero que mi link se parezca a un botón, el link me lleva a otro lado de la página.
El código del link que uso es:

```
<a herf=#"Caracteristicas">características</a>
<a name="Caracteristicas">Caracteristicas</a>
```

Y puedo poner esos links aparezcan cuando presione un botón?

Comment: ¿Nos compartes qué has intentado por favor?

Comment: Aquí ya tienes posibles respuestas. Para qué escribir otra pregunta idéntica?

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas usar CSS, agrega la clase `button` a tus links y puedes utilizar un CSS como el siguiente.

```css
a.button {
  background-color: #4CAFF0; /* Tu color */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com" class="button">Ir a Google</a>
```

Para hacer que aparezcan más botones al dar click a uno, necesitas utilizar Javascript.

Comment: Por qué inline block?

Comment: para evitar que la etiqueta `<a>` ocupe un `width: 100%` y solo utilice el ancho del texto escrito, aunque no es necesario, pero para evitar cualquier cosa

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas sencillo es agregarle una clase a un etiqueta `<a>` de la siguiente manera:

```
<a href="#" class="btn">características</a>
```

Y con eso ya puedes mandar a llamar esa clase desde un css extra, con las siguientes propiedades:

```css
.btn {
  /*Para evitar bordes no deseados en el boton*/
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  /*Le damos un padding para que tenga un pequeño margen al interior del boton*/
  padding: 10px 20px;
  /*El color del texto sera blanco, puedes utilizar codigo rgba() o hexadecimal*/
  color: white;
  /*Aquí eliminamos los estilos de la etiqueta <a>*/
  text-decoration: none;
  /*Le damos un pequeño borde al boton para que tenga un mejor estilo*/
  border-radius: 8px;
  /*Y se aplica un cursor: pointer, para que cambie el cursor*/
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">características</a>
```